# How to create softlinks to all files in a directory in a different directory in terminal?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

Doing `ln -fs ./source/*` at the destination directory doesn't work

It shows:

```
./source/file1 is not a directory
```

Answer (score 3):

From `man ln`:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
>    ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
>    ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
>    ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> In  the 1st form, create a link to TARGET with the name LINK_NAME.  In the 2nd form, create a link to TARGET in the current directory.  In the 3rd and 4th forms, create links to each TARGET in DIRECTORY.  Create hard links by default, symbolic links with --symbolic.

Reading it carefully, you'll see that (assuming that the source folder contains more than one file) you used the 3rd form. Since you didn't specify a directory, the last filename is interpreted as directory.

If you are inside the directory you want to create the symlinks in, you can simply add `.` (current directory) at the end of the command:

```
ln -fs ./source/* .
```

Comment: Can you give an example of this please?

Comment: @bhargavuk sorry, my wording was confusing. Just do exactly what you described in the question, except that you add a space and a `.` at the end of the command, i.e. run the command I included at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted/needed to do something and @danzel gave the best answer. Here's what I needed: create a symbolic within the WordPress’ plugin folder to another folder within the root of the WordPress installation.

1. navigate to the folder
2. make sure I am in the right folder
3. list all the items in the folder
4. create the symbolic link

Here are the commands:

```
$ cd wp-content/plugins
$ pwd
$ ls -al
$ ln -s ../../my-folder-with-subfolders/subfolder-name/* .
$ ln -s ../../my-folder-with-subfolders/another-subfolder/* .
```